# Adobe Software and 3D Studio Max on Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, 3ds-max

Is windows 7 home edition sufficient for running adobe's software (Illustrator, Photoshop) and 3D Studio max, or do I need the pro or ultimate editions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Any version of Windows 7 can run Adobe's applications and 3D Studio Max just fine. You don't need a special version of Windows to run those applications, however, I would go for a 64-bit version of Windows 7. It's more likely that you'll be bound by your hardware than the Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a Home Premium, not a Home Basic?

The Home edition has no restrictions on the type of software it can run. However, if you can afford Illustrator, Photoshop and 3D Studio Max, a Pro or Ultimate license is not **that** expensive ...

Comment: Yeah it's the home premium. And it's buying the Adobe and 3dmax software that make me have to pinch pennies :) thanks